# How to prevent lag in form while moving?

Tags: vb.net, forms, animation, lag, ui-thread

When moving the form from side to side, it gives a small lag while checking every 5 seconds (using timer) a request in JSON from a website, is there any way to prevent this problem?

**Sample Image**

[image]

**Here is the Code**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Try

        Dim jsonName = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=" & ChannelID & "&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(title))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
        Dim rqn As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonName.ReadToEnd)
        ChannelName = $"{rqn.SelectToken("items")(0)("snippet")("title")}"

        Label3.Text = ChannelName

        Dim json = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" & ChannelID & "&fields=items(statistics(subscriberCount))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
        Dim rq As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json.ReadToEnd)
        Subs = $"{Convert.ToDecimal(rq.SelectToken("items")(0)("statistics")("subscriberCount")).ToString("#,###,###")}"

        Label1.Text = Subs

    Catch ex As Exception

        Timer1.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao tentar Conseguir os Dados do Canal!")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running the requests async?

Comment: No, I don't know how you do it.

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker or Task to keep code from interfering with the UI thread.

Comment: But how am I going to call this code? It's not a function, I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/walkthrough-accessing-the-web-by-using-async-and-await) operations may solve your problem

I can't properly test the code, but as shown bellow, changing the `sub` to a `Async Sub` and changing `GetResponse` to `GetResponseAsync` adding the `await` keword should do it.

```
Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 

    Try

        Dim jsonName = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(Await DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=" & ChannelID & "&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(title))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponseAsync, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
        Dim rqn As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonName.ReadToEnd)
        ChannelName = $"{rqn.SelectToken("items")(0)("snippet")("title")}"

        Label3.Text = ChannelName

        Dim json = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(Await DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" & ChannelID & "&fields=items(statistics(subscriberCount))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponseAsync, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
        Dim rq As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json.ReadToEnd)
        Subs = $"{Convert.ToDecimal(rq.SelectToken("items")(0)("statistics")("subscriberCount")).ToString("#,###,###")}"

        Label1.Text = Subs

    Catch ex As Exception

        Timer1.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao tentar Conseguir os Dados do Canal!")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, that await task.run was not supossed to né there